# Twilio - Get List of Opt-Outs

Tags: c#, twilio

I am new to Twilio.  I built a sender to send out a recent texting campaign.  Unfortunately, even though I built a webhook to process responses, it failed during my process of sending out about 40,000 texts.  I have got the MVC webhook running now, but I missed all Twilio posts with incoming message info for anyone who opted out from the 40,000 people.  I would like to mark these people as an Opt-Out in my SQL Server database, so I don't attempt to send to them again.  I tried to download a CSV of the received messages, but the last 4 digits of the phone number it was sent from is X'd out.  I have nothing to match on.  Is there another way to fix things manually?

Comment: Have you tried using the [API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/api/message-resource) to lookup messages?  Does it still redact the phone number?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio does not have a built in capability for this. However here are some thing's I do with my application.

1. You can write a script using the Messaging API to see which of of 'direction: incoming' messages include your opt out keywords. Here you can export a list of phone numbers
2. You can always send the messages out again, and if you had stop messaging build into your Twilio account, Twilio will block the sending to the unsubscribed users. You will likely see a 21610 error code. See https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21610